# java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to display List<String> in JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm getting very strange problem in JSF page when I try to display Java `List<String>` with countries in JSF page. This is the code:

```
 private List<String> listCountries;

    // Get the list with Countries
    public List<String> getlistCountries() { 
        // Generate List of Countries
        initlistCountries();
        return listCountries;
    }

    public void initlistCountries(){
        listCountries.add("Afghanistan");
        listCountries.add("Albania");
        listCountries.add("Algeria");
        listCountries.add("Andorra");
        listCountries.add("Angola");
        ......
    }
```

Is this code correct? I can't use `@PostConstruct` because I have use it already.

I get his error when I load the JSF page:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.DX_57.AC_57.AddAccount.initlistCountries(AddAccount.java:344)
    at com.DX_57.AC_57.AddAccount.getlistCountries(AddAccount.java:339)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't initialized `listCountries` so make it

```
 public void initlistCountries(){
        listCountries = new ArrayList<String>();
        listCountries.add("Afghanistan");
        listCountries.add("Albania");
        listCountries.add("Algeria");
        listCountries.add("Andorra");
        listCountries.add("Angola");
        ......
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the arraylist.

```
private List<String> listCountries=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you ever initialized listCountries.

```
public void initlistCountries()
{
        listCountries = new ArrayList< String >(); // Add this line.

        listCountries.add("Afghanistan");
        listCountries.add("Albania");
        listCountries.add("Algeria");
        listCountries.add("Andorra");
        listCountries.add("Angola");
        ......
}
```